# raise exception in __init__ if parameter not found

Tags: python

I have a construction like:

```
def __init__(self, my_param): 
    if my_param:
        self.my_param = my_param
    else:
        raise MYException()
```

and I am using this value somewhere like `value=self.my_param`

but when I dont pass the `my_param` it doesnot raise exception but says `class object does not have my_param`

How can I raise it properly?

Comment: Assign it some default value, for example `object()` and then check if its value is different than the default value.

Comment: You've goofed your class definition. Post the whole thing. And don't retype it, *copy and paste the exact thing*.

Comment: Please show how you instantiate the class and the actual traceback.

Comment: The way you have structured your `__init__` method, `my_param` is not optional so there is no way it cannot be passed.

Answer (score 3):

Actually When you don't pass an argument to your function, raising an `TypeError` exception is exactly what python does by itself, which I think There is no need to override this exception :) :

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

But you can also use `*args` to pass a tuple of arguments to your constructor in order to check the validity of `args` which will pass an empty tuple if you don't pass anything:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if args:
            self.param = args[0]
        else:
            raise Exception("Please pass a parameter to instance")
```

Also as a practical and not pythonic approach you can use a decorator to wrap your constructor:

```
def my_exp(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        if args:
            return func(*args)
        else:
            raise Exception("Pleas pass an argument to instance")
    return wrapper()

class a(object):
    @my_exp
    def __init__(self, my_param):
        self.param = my_param
```

Demo :

```
instance = a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kasra/Desktop/ex2.py", line 11, in <module>
    class a(object):
  File "/home/kasra/Desktop/ex2.py", line 12, in a
    @my_exp
  File "/home/kasra/Desktop/ex2.py", line 9, in my_exp
    return wrapper()
  File "/home/kasra/Desktop/ex2.py", line 8, in wrapper
    raise Exception("Pleas pass an argument to instance")
Exception: Pleas pass an argument to instance
```

You can also use another tools like `functools.wraps` or etc. in order to create more flexible decorators. But still I recommend to let python does the job for you!

Comment: @aryan You can just pass `*args` to constructor too. Checkout the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
def __init__(self, my_param=None):
    if my_param:
        self.my_param = my_param
    else:
        raise MYException()
```